# Micro service Registry in Play Framework

Tags: spring-boot, playframework, microservices

How do we register microservice in Play Framework? Like in Spring Boot we use 
@EnableEurekaServer in the main class.

Comment: What do you mean by registering a microservice?

Comment: Like to discover a microservices we use Eureka Server in Spring boot so that Client Service can access, So what we need to do in Play(or How a microservice will talk another microservice in Play)